# how i can cut the internet connection for 1 min by cmd or something else?

Tags: networking, shell, teamviewer

I’m testing a remote computer having an access to our server, some of the tests require to cut the internet in order to see a specific behavior for our tests.

I’m using TeamViewer for this tests, I can disconnect the internet using TeamViewer, but i can't reconnect (TeamViewer connection will be lost).

how can I use TeamViewer to cut the internet 1 min and automatically the remote computer reconnect it self (If there a command for that?) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this process using a batch file with the following code:

```
netsh interface set interface ethernet disable
timeout 60
netsh interface set interface ethernet enable
```

- Change both instances of `ethernet` to match the name of the network adapter you wish to temporarily disable. You can find this name by running `ncpa.cpl`.
- The batch file must be run as administrator each time you use it in order for the `netsh` command to work.
- Fortunately, you can bypass the need to manually choose `Run as Administrator` each time you use your batch file by creating a shortcut to the batch file, then enabling the shortcut's `Run as Administrator` option. You can then run the shortcut normally and it will automatically run the batch file as administrator each time.

[image]